# Laravel não instala

Tags: laravel, composer

```
kalil@debian:~$ composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to /home/kalil/.config/composer
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.4.12): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.8.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.4.12): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.8.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.4.12): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.4.12): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing laravel/installer (v2.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log-implementation (For using the console logger)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
kalil@debian:~$ laravel
bash: laravel: comando não encontrado
```

Já tentei reinstalar tudo e da esse erro quando tento rodar o Laravel

Answer (score 0):

O erro que está sendo apresentado é exibido porque o bash não encontrou uma definição válida para o comando `laravel`. Para definir o comando, basta executar o procedimento abaixo.

Abra o arquivo `.bashrc` com o seu editor preferido

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Adicione o seguinte texto ao arquivo e salve

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Execute o seguinte comando no terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Reinicie o terminal e agora deve estar tudo em ordem.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente necessita da configuração de PATH como explicado no comentário acima e também na documentação do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6),

> macOS: $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
>
> GNU / Linux Distributions: $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin

Porém possui uma outra maneira de se utilizar o laravel sem a necessidade de instalar o laravel, e acaba se tornando uma maneira mais simples, que também esta definida na documentação:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog